# Does the integration by parts formula $\int f'g = - \int fg'$ hold true for compactly supported, continuous functions of bounded variation?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, bounded-variation

Assume that $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ is a continuous function of bounded variation with support in $[-T,T]$. We know that $f$ is differentiable almost everywhere. Further, let $g \in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$ be bounded. Does the integration by parts formula
$$
\int f'(x)g(x) \,dx = -\int f(x)g'(x) \, dx
$$
hold true?

Comment: Yes, if $f'$ is understood as a measure; no, otherwise.

Comment: I edited the question: What I mean is the integral w.r.t the Lebesgue measure. Is it true in true in this case?

Comment: Then the answer is no (btw, there must be a minus sign even in the regular case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $T > 1$ and let $f = \chi_{[0,1]}$ be the characteristic function of $[0,1]$.
Then
$$
\int_{-T}^T f g' = \int_0^1 g' = g(1) - g(0).
$$
On the other hand, since $f' = 0$ a.e.,
$$
\int_{-T}^T f' g = 0.
$$

If we understand $f'$ as the measure-valued derivative $Df$ of a BV function, then $Df = \delta_0 - \delta_{-1}$, and
$$
\int_{-T}^T g\, Df = g(0) - g(1),
$$
that coincides with $-\int_{-T}^T f g'$.

Comment: If we assume in addition that $f$ is continuous on whole $\mathbb{R}$ can we then find a similar argument?

Comment: The answer is again negative, because $Df$ can have a Cantor part. The argument works only if $f$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: @Rigel Under what circumstances we can regard $f'$ as both a measure and function so that the both integrals coincide?